# Running multiple queries in mongo`

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I have a collection and want to get a set of results that met a set of conditions. I understand the Mongo doesn't let you use joins so I would need to run separate queries and join the results into a single response.

But is it possible to join the results of separate queries together to get the intended output.

Are there any basic examples I could see query results joined together.

Thanks

For example could I join these two queries so I get the results of both queries:

```
coll.find({"coordinates.type" : "Point"},{"coordinates" :1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

and:

```
coll.find({"place.bounding_box.type" : "Polygon"},{"place.bounding_box.coordinates" : 1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

Comment: What kind of examples do you want to see? Each code is different and application specific. Better tell people what you have you in  your app for getting specific help.

Comment: I've edited question with more specifics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, you do not need to run those queries separately. You can join the results like so:

```
coll.find(
  { $or : [ 
      { "coordinates.type" : "Point" }, 
      { "place.bounding_box.type" : "Polygon" } 
    ] 
  },
  {"coordinates" :1, "place.bounding_box.coordinates" : 1}
)
```

You can also use $and / [$elementMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch) instead of an $or